# color of JButton

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

After reviewing many previous StackOverflow posts, I am still unable to get my JButton to be black instead of the default color. Here is what my button looks like:

[image: This is what my button looks like.]

And here's my code:

```
public void setStartButton() {

    JPanel panel = this.jPanel1;
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton button = new JButton("START");

    // size and location of start button
    int res = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
    int length = (int) Math.floor(10.0*res/25.4); // side lengths of square button
    int offset = length/2; // because button should be centered...but its x and y location are given by its upper left hand corner
    button.setBounds(centerX-offset, centerY-offset, length, length);

    // color of start button
    button.setBackground(BLACK);
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    // font
    button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 8));

    button.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(button);

}
```

By the way, when I change `setContentAreaFilled` to `true`, it makes no difference.

I know that the function is indeed being called, because the location and font info for my button is working just fine.

Any assistance would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Change BLACK to Color.BLACK. Also make sure you `import java.awt.Color`

Comment: Well, I had already imported `import static java.awt.Color.BLACK;`, so that should have worked, right?

Comment: And seriously consider using an appropriate layout manager

Comment: I don't believe I can do that here because I have to draw the button at different coordinates on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JButton` is made of a series of layers, including the `content`, `border` and `focus` layers.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you may need to remove all of them, for example...

[image: Button]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setStartButton();
    }

    public void setStartButton() {

        JButton button = new JButton("START");
        button.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        // color of start button
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(true);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setBackground(BLACK);
        button.setForeground(WHITE);

        // font
        button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 8));
        add(button);

    }

}
```

I'd also strongly encourage you to consider making use of an appropriate layout manager and using the properties of it and the `JButton` to generate the desired padding you need, these will work together with the font metrics, which tend to be different between systems, to generate an appropriate size for the button